# Slow image streaming from Resources using Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, gridview, universal-image-loader

I'm creating an app with two activities thus far.  Each activity is nothing but a gridview full of pictures in the drawables folder.  However, these images are loading incredibly slowly.  On a tablet, I may have 24 pictures on screen at a time.  These pictures are 256*144 and average around 60KB.  It takes approximately 8 seconds to load a page if I swipe far enough to need to reset all views.  This doesn't seem right.

All the pictures in the two activities total ~8MB of space.

I'm currently using the Universal Image Loader, but am not opposed to another method if there are better ones.

Here is my array adapter code.

```
    import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context context;
    private int columnSize;
    private int rowSize;
    private boolean flag;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    private ImageLoaderConfiguration config;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

public ImageAdapter(Context c, int cS, int rS, boolean f, ImageLoader img){
    context = c;
    columnSize = cS;
    rowSize = rS;
    flag = f;
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheInMemory().build();
    config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
    imageLoader = img;
}
```

(nothing special with other methods)

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ImageView icon;

    if(convertView==null){
        icon = new ImageView(context);
        icon.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(columnSize, rowSize));
        icon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        icon.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
    } else {
        icon = (ImageView)convertView;
    }

    String filename = null;



    if(flag){
        filename = "h" + Integer.toString(position);
    } else if(!flag){
        filename = "i" + Integer.toString(position);
    }

    int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(filename, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    String uri = "drawable://" + Integer.toString(id);
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(uri, icon, options);
    //icon.setImageResource(id);

    return icon;
}
```

}

Edit: Forgot some code.  Here is the Image Adapter that is passed into my adapter code from a fragment's `onCreateView` method

```
ImageLoader img = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        img.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(fragView.getContext()));
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(fragView.getContext(),columnSize, rowSize, true, img));
```

Comment: getIdentifier uses reflection which can be incredibly slow, especially since you're trying to do a few dozen lookups all at once. Try and find an alternate solution that doesn't require the use of that. Also, you're getting a layout inflator in every single getView call for no reason. You aren't using it

Comment: You could always keep an int array of your images. Ex. `int[] imageIds = new int[] { R.drawable.h0, R.drawable.h1, .... } `and reference it by `int id = imageIds [position];`

Comment: So I made some changes.  I call getIdentifier in the constructor to prevent it from calling while scrolling, and I stored those integers in an array.  However, there is no noticeable increase in speed.  Any other ideas?